# Blank temperature in iOS 8 Weather app (showing just underscores)

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios, temperature

Since upgrading to iOS 8 on iPhone, the Weather app will occasionally show a "blank" temperature (using an underscore: _ for each empty digit, so two underscores: __). The blank temperature also appears in Notification Center.

It is like this about 40% of the time. I imagine this doesn't affect everyone, but that it is instead affecting only temperature data for certain cities? Has anyone else experienced this and know how to fix it?

It's been like this ever since iOS 8 first came out on September 17, 2014, and since then I have tried killing the Weather app, restarting my device, etc. and none of those worked.

Comment: Does this happen for any city? Is it just for your current location?

Comment: I get that if my connection is poor - only for current location unless I'm completely off-air.

Comment: I'm usually on WiFi, and my connection is almost always full bars. And I still get blank temperatures.

Comment: Does this still happen on iOS 10? Seems like it's a bug that may have been fixed.

Comment: I don't think I've had a blank temperature in a few months now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since upgrading to iOS 10, I haven't had a blank temperature appear in the Weather app anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If the blank temperature is associated with a page that also has a blank city, then the problem might be that you have not allowed the Weather app to "always" access location data.

You can check the setting by going to "Settings" --> "Privacy" --> "Location Services".

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me after an upgrade, wipe, and restore from iCloud.  Only temperature that displayed was the local determined automatically by the location.

The fix was to delete all the cities and re-add them.

Comment: Thanks, but the blank temperature is for the "Local" page, which AFAIK cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had to turn on Location services *and* turn off my VPN. The app worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Apple, and they told me to go into Settings, turn off Location Services, **reboot**, and then turn Location Services back on. Go straight to the Weather app to allow it to refresh. This fixed the issue for me on my devices, and they don't work perfectly, but they are much more reliable than before.

Answer (score -1):

on my iphone 6 . ios 10 . I have my privacy > location services > weather > never .

Clear off all cities from widget first. Then go to 
settings > cellular > weather > toggle on . 
From your home screen swipe right > Go to the weather widget and tap set up weather > enter the name of the city .

After the first city loads > Tap the city name > In the bottom right you can add more cities.

To change the order that the city appear > hold the bottom one and drag it upward

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer's the OP's question.  Can you please clarify this in your answer?